# Contains() in a Where clause fails on Oracle if the list contains more than 1000 elements , using LINQ ef core .net

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle, ef-core-2.0

In asp.net using ef core linq and oracle, it is not possible to get data using where clause contains( >1000) greater than a thousand ids. Is there any alternate option for it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes; store those IDs into a table and use it in a subquery. For example: instead of

```
where id in (1, 2, 3, ..., 5000)
```

it would be

```
where id in (select id from separate_table)
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need this using LINQ query in ef core.
var itemIds = (1, 2, 3 .............5000)
 _context.items.where(a=> itemIds.contains(a.id)).ToList()

Comment: You're welcome; unfortunately, I can't help with that, all I know is that Oracle SQL's IN clause can't accept more than 1000 values.